# Git: Two initial commits

Tags: git, branch

I have a project which recently began using version control.
There is an older attempt at this project with completely different code, which I want to add to version control for posterity but which is neither an ancestor nor a descendent of the initial commit of the current `master` branch.

I wish to create a new parallel branch for this with no previous history (i.e. to have multiple "initial commits". Is this possible with Git without having to create a second repository? The commit tree would look something like this:

```
o---o---o   master
     \
      o---o   branch

o   old implementation
```

Such that I can simply use `git checkout old` to access the code. It must not be cleaned up by the garbage collector after 90 days, and may optionally be tagged.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`git checkout` has an option for exactly such use case: `--orphan`.

From the Git manual:

> `--orphan <new_branch>`
>
> Create a new orphan branch, named `<new_branch>`, started from `<start_point>` and switch to it. The first commit made on this new branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.

Also, the man says explicitly:

> If you want to start a disconnected history that records a set of paths that is totally different from the one of `<start_point>`, then you should clear the index and the working tree right after creating the orphan branch by running "`git rm -rf .`" from the top level of the working tree.

Comment: Thank you. As you may have gathered from my question, I was thinking in terms of creating a "parallel branch" and so had been reading all the `git-branch` help, rather than `git checkout`!

Comment: Well, it's not that git is known for it's intuitive and consistent interface ;)

Answer (score 9):

Apart from using the `checkout --orphan` method, you can as well create a separate repository in your other code base, make the initial commit, and then push to the other repository (or from the other repository pull from this one)

```
cd old-code
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit of historical codebase'
git push ../path/to/current/code/repository master:historical
```

After that you can remove the repository again (`rm -rf old-code/.git`) if you don't need it (but it shouldn't hurt)

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an orphan branch:

```
git checkout --orphan <branch>
```